# Draw a green dashed line in ggplot separating people whose annual income is in the upper half from the rest

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: 1]]

We are given data on the annual income along with ages. A part of the problem is to "Draw a green dashed line separating people whose annual income is in the upper half from the rest." I know how to format the line but not sure how to code it that it is to separate the data (Which I believe should be placed at the astrik).

In addition, the graph that does show, does not seem to have a smoothing line. Is it because it is hidden behind the points of is it not graphed?

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = ss16wa, aes(AGEP, WAGP, color = SEX, shape = CIT,  alpha = 0.5)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  geom_line(color = "green", linetype = "dashed" * ) + 
  xlab("Age") + ylab("Annual income, $")
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset ? (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You're looking for a reference line so you see `geom_abline`.

Comment: You passed data only to geom_point. If you want the data to be used by all the from function u should specify it with ggplot2()

Answer (score 1):

You can use `geom_hline` to draw a horizontal line that will match the median of the income:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = age, y = value, color= sex))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = median(df$value), linetype = "dashed", color = "green", size = 2) + 
  xlab("Age") + ylab("Annual income, $")
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

---

NB: Regarding your question about `geom_smooth` not display, it is difficult to answer it without a reproducible example. Please provide a reproducible example in order people can try to solve our issue with `geom_smooth`

NB: You don't need to add `alpha = 0.5` into `aes` as you are using a fixed value

---

**Reproducible example**

```r
df <- data.frame(value = sample(1:10000,500,replace = TRUE),
                 age = sample(20:65,500, replace = TRUE),
                 sex = sample(c("M","F"),500, replace = TRUE))
```